# how to pass model with jquery ajax post with datetime

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

On my button click i am passing model to the controller with datetime objects in that in my local database it is working fine but when i upload to server the datetime value is taking null.how to resolve this problem.
this is my code for button click

```
$('#btnTaxiCall').on('click', function () {
stopCallTime();
var TaxiCallTime = new Date();
//alert(TaxiCallTime.toUTCString());
// $('#TaxiCallTime').val(TaxiCallTime.toISOString());
$('#TaxiCallTime').val($.date(TaxiCallTime));
            var model = $("#formTaxiLog").serializeArray();
            $('#btnTaxiArrival').removeAttr('disabled');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/TaxiLog/Add', type: 'Post', dataType: 'json',
                data: $.param(model),
                success: function (data) { $('#btnTaxiCall').css({ backgroundColor: 'green' }); isSaved = true; Id = data.id; $('#CallTime button').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); $('#ErrMsg').hide(); $('#CallTime div').removeClass('customValidation'); $("#Id").val(Id); }
            });

$.date = function (dateObject) {
       // alert(dateObject);
        var d = new Date(dateObject);
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var hours = d.getHours();
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var seconds = d.getSeconds()
        var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hours + ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes + ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;

        return date;
    }

public int Post(TaxiLogVM vm)
{
using (var dc = new SGSDBContext())
{
            string sql = "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM [dbo].[Venue] WHERE [Id]={0};";
            if (dc.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql, vm.VenueId).FirstOrDefault() == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                vm.CreatedDate = vm.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                //vm.TaxiArrivalTime = null;
                sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TaxiLog]([VenueId],[UserId],[Title],[Name],[Destination],[TaxiFirmId],[TaxiCallTime],[TaxiArrivalTime],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) "
                    + "VALUES({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}); "
                    + "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
                vm.Id = (int)dc.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(sql, vm.VenueId, vm.UserId, vm.Title, vm.Name, vm.Destination, vm.TaxiFirmId, vm.TaxiCallTime.Value.ToString(" hh:mm:ss tt"), SqlDateTime.Null, vm.CreatedDate, vm.ModifiedDate).FirstOrDefault();
                dc.SaveChanges();

                return vm.Id;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem with my code.anybody help me

Comment: plz show your controller action and model code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `datetime` to controller you should pass it as a `string`, and then parse into `datetime` in controller.

Make a string property that convert your datetime to string.

```
public string MyDateTimeString
{
  get{ return datetime.toString();}
  set{ datetime = Convert.toDateTime(value);}
}
```

Comment: in viewmodel im taking datetime type for that field

Comment: i have to use only datetime for my viewmodel

Comment: there are another issues with my date time if my another datetime columns is empty it is throwing the error.so im using datetime? type